# how to reference an object in a Fragment from the parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a mainActivity with viewPager and three tabs, each tab has its respective fragment.

in one of the fragments, i declared an object as `public`, and i want to refer to this object from the mainActivity that hosts this `Fragment` "tab".

what i attempted is, since in the mainActivity i have alist of `Fragments`:

```
this.fragList.add(new Frag1());
this.fragList.add(new Frag2());
this.fragList.add(new Frag3());
```

i called `this.fragList.get(0).obj` but this did not work.

how can i achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean "did not work"? Did you get any errors or what?

Comment: How do you declare your fragList? Is it typed? (ie. List<Whatever>)? what errors do you get?

Comment: @vinitius no errors the object is just not listed among the accessible properties of the "fragList.get(0).xxxx"

Comment: @kha yes private List<Fragment> fragList

Comment: @rmaik There's your answer `List<Fragment>`. Fragments don't have have your custom object. Do a cast to your fragment type like: `((YourFragment)this.fragList.get(0)).obj`

Comment: @vinitius not working, i tried "(Frag1) fragList.get(0).obj" and it is still not listed among te othe properties

Comment: Change it to ((Frag1) fragList.get(0)).obj and it will work

Comment: @rmaik should be: `((Frag1)fragList.get(0)).obj`